# Giving publishing rights to a deployment to another user

Tags: google-app-maker

Can I give another person publishing rights to my deployment? If so, how?

I tried adding the other person to 'Admins' of that deployment, but at least the rights haven't updated, as I did it approx. 30 minutes ago. I also just published it, and the rights have not updated.

Of course, they could make their own deployment, but then the URL would change. Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: It is not possible to let other users to publish deployment you own at this time.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a bug -- [Google's documentation about App Maker](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/security/secure-your-app#deployment_actions_and_project_sharing) describes the ability to do this in detail, but there are no such actions visible in the app.

That documentation says "A project owner also has full access to the data in all deployments of the app, even if the project or deployments restrict the owner from having that access (because the project owner can give themself access)." and "An app owner can take ownership of a deployment." and even has a section "Take ownership of a deployment" saying "If the owner of a deployment edits or republishes a deployment that an editor originally published, this takes ownership of the deployment."

We can report this to google.